# MySql Error de Sintaxis en Trigger

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger, sintaxis

No consigo averiguar el error
Código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_forum_message_like AFTER INSERT ON forum_message_likes FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE new_fmi INTEGER(11);
  SET @new_fmi = NEW.forum_message_id;
  IF NEW.dislike = true THEN 
    UPDATE forum_messages SET dislikes = (dislikes + 1) WHERE forum_messages.id = NEW.forum_message_id;
  ELSE THEN 
    UPDATE forum_messages SET dislikes = likes + 1 WHERE id = NEW.forum_message_id; 
  END IF;
END;
```

Error:

> CREATE TRIGGER new_forum_message_like AFTER INSERT ON
> forum_message_likes FOR EACH ROW BEGIN    DECLARE new_fmi INTEGER(11)
> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El trigger tiene algunos errores de sintaxis, por ejemplo el ELSE nunca lleva la palabra THEN  a la par. Intenta modificarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER new_forum_message_like AFTER INSERT ON forum_message_likes
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
          DECLARE new_fmi INT(11);
          SET @new_fmi = NEW.forum_message_id;
          IF NEW.dislike = true THEN 
            UPDATE forum_messages SET dislikes = (dislikes + 1) WHERE forum_messages.id = NEW.forum_message_id;
          ELSE  
            UPDATE forum_messages SET dislikes = likes + 1 WHERE id = NEW.forum_message_id; 
          END IF;
       END;//
```